# Returning char pointer to a different files

Tags: c

Is it possible to return a char Pointer even the calling function is not in the same file.... if I call the function for example:

```
 void gotest(sqlite3 *pt,char *nutzers)
{
    char string[1064];
    char *text;
    text = get_data_byName(pt,"whatever",string);   
    printf("test %s \n\n\n same file",text);    
}

 char *get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr,char *user,char *resulter)
{
    .......
    resulter = "TestCall";
    return resulter;
}
```

if `gotest(sqlite3 *pt,char *nutzers)` and `char *get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr,char *user,char *resulter)` are in different files then gcc gives the following

**Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast**

if I have both functions in one file everything works fine.

compiling like:

```
gcc -o test test.c time.c database.c libircclient-1.6/src/libircclient.o -lsqlite3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need headers for your files. If GCC doesn't see a function prototype *in the file it's used in*, GCC assumes that the function returns an `int`. You need to read up on headers. In the mean time, putting this in the file where you use `get_data_byName` will be enough:

```
char *get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr,char *user,char *resulter);
```

You have to remember that although when GCC is linking, it knows that you define `get_data_byName`, when it's compiling, it needs to know what parameters and return values it has. That's the purpose of a header. Headers contain function prototypes. A function prototype looks like this:

```
char *get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr,char *user,char *resulter);
```

If you put the prototypes of all of the functions defined in one `.c` file in one `.h` file, and them `#include` that header in the files that use the function, you wont get that error anymore. So if you have a file called `get_data_by_name.c`, this would be `get_data_by_name.h`:

```
#ifndef GET_DATA_BY_NAME_H
#define GET_DATA_BY_NAME_H
char *get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr,char *user,char *resulter);
#endif
```

Then just `#include` it in the file that uses `get_data_byName`:

```
#include "get_data_by_name.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the error not because the functions are in different files: it is perfectly fine for functions from different compilation units to call each other. The real problem is that you are trying to call a function from the other file without providing a *prototype*. When this happens, C assumes a return type of `int`.

Make a header file with this content:

get_data_byName.h

```
char *get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr,char *user,char *resulter);
```

Now include this header file in both of your C files:

#include "get_data_byName.h"

The compilation warning will go away.

Answer (score 2):

There must be no declaration of `get_data_byName()` visible to `gotest()`, so the compiler generates an implicit declaration and assigns a return type of `int`, hence the warning. To resolve add a declaration for `get_data_byName()`, in a header file for example, and ensure it is visible to `gotest()`.

`get_data.h`:

```
#ifndef GET_DATA_HEADER_H_
#define GET_DATA_HEADER_H_

extern char* get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr,char *user,char *resulter);

#endif
```

Then `#include <get_data.h>` in the `.c` file where `gotest()` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's certainly possible. You need to have a *declaration* of the function before calling it:

```
char * get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr, char *user, char *resulter);
```

Also, you should *really* use `const` for pointers where applicable.

And remember that if you need to return a non-literal string, you need to think about memory management.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how you have them "in separate files."  The format specified in K&R would require 2 extra .h files for each .c file you have.  The .h files would declare the function prototypes.  From there, you can include the file_2.h into your file_1.c, and make get_data_byName available to gotest.  Hope that helps.

```
**file_1.c**
include "file_1.h"
include "file_2.h"

void gotest(sqlite3 *pt,char *nutzers)
{
    char string[1064];
    char *text;
    text = get_data_byName(pt,"whatever",string);   
    printf("test %s \n\n\n same file",text);    
}


**file_2.c**
char *get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr,char *user,char *resulter)
{
    .......
    resulter = "TestCall";
    return resulter;
} 

**file_1.h**
void gotest(sqlite3 *pt,char *nutzers);

**file_2.h**
char *get_data_byName(sqlite3 *ptr,char *user,char *resulter);
```